# Dynamically add a select element to div, mousedown event prevents dropdown from opening

Tags: javascript, jquery

There's a DIV element (id: container) which has a mousedown event handler attached. Then I appended a select element into it, using document.createElement(...) and append(...). 
The problem is that the dropdown list does not open when I click on the arrow of the select element. 
Please note that the container element is part of an existing webpage/crm. It cannot be modified.

```
// container:
$("#container").on('mousedown.something', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // some other code
});

// append a select to the container
var numbers = ["Numbers", "1", "2", "3"];

           var list = document.createElement('select');

           list.setAttribute("id", "dropdown");
           for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
               var opt = document.createElement('option');
               opt.innerHTML = numbers[i];
               opt.value = numbers[i];
               list.appendChild(opt);
           }
$('#container').append(list);
```

jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/tomsx/8tLjcgbh/

Comment: It there no other possibility? The container cannot be modified as stated above: "Please note that the container element is part of an existing webpage/crm. It cannot be modified."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `e.stopPropagation()` on `select` mousedown event

```js
$("#container").on('mousedown.something', function(event) {   
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('MouseDown');
 // some other code
});

var numbers = ["Numbers", "1", "2", "3"];

          var list = document.createElement('select');

          list.setAttribute("id", "dropdown");
          for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
              var opt = document.createElement('option');
              opt.innerHTML = numbers[i];
              opt.value = numbers[i];
              list.appendChild(opt);
          }
$('#container').append(list);

//stop the container mousedown from the created select
$('#container').on('mousedown' , '> select' , function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">Click me</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You event is trigger on the select as well (being a part of the container) so you need to trigger the mousedown only if the click is on the container element

```
 $("#container").on('mousedown.something', function(event) {   
 if($(event.target).is('#container')) {
        event.preventDefault();
   // some other code
}
});
```

Comment: It there no other possibility than modifying the event handler? The container cannot be modified as stated above: "Please note that the container element is part of an existing webpage/crm. It cannot be modified."

Comment: you can create a new event handler that overrides this event handler

Answer (score 0):

Reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

- passive: A Boolean which, if true, indicates that the function specified by listener will never call preventDefault(). If a passive listener does call preventDefault(), the user agent will do nothing other than generate a console warning. See Improving scrolling performance with passive listeners to learn more.

So you need to set **passive :true** in addEventlistener

```
var numbers = ["Numbers", "1", "2", "3"];
var list = document.createElement('select');
list.setAttribute("id", "dropdown");
for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = numbers[i];
    opt.value = numbers[i];
    list.appendChild(opt);
}
$('#container').append(list);
$("#container").on('mousedown.something', function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
    // some other code
},{passive:true});
```